# Sum Calculation in Gridview Using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I have a problem here..Before I proceed I will try to explain my problem , I have a grid view with a check boxes, text box(Marks1), text box(Marks2) and a label to show the sum of Marks1 and Marks 2.

If I update the particular marks1 and marks 2 whose check box is checked, immediately sum should be changed or updated.

Here is Java Script page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectChange(ChkId, txt1, txt2, total) {
            var chk = document.getElementById(ChkId);
            UpdateField(ChkId, txt1, txt2,total)

        }

        function UpdateField(ChkId, txt1, txt2, total) {
            if (document.getElementById(chkID).checked == true) {
                var txtval1 = document.getElementById(txt1).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txt1).value : "0";
                var txtval2 = document.getElementById(txt2).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txt2).value : "0";
                var total1 = parseInt(txtval1) + parseInt(txtval2);
                document.getElementById(total).innerHTML = total1;
                if (document.getElementById(txt1).value == "" && document.getElementById(txt2).value == "") {
                    document.getElementById(total).innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById(txt1).disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById(txt2).disabled = false;
                }


            } else {
                document.getElementById(txt1).disabled = true;
                document.getElementById(txt2).disabled = true;

            }
        }

    </script>
```

and I used Row Data bound event for setting attributes of check box, and text box.. like this:

```
protected void Gdview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox txt1 =(TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("Txtmark1");
                TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Txtmark2");
                Label lb1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbTotal");
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("Checker");

                chk.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:return SelectChange('" + chk.ClientID + "','" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + lb1.ClientID + "')";
                txt1.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript:return UpdateField('" + chk.ClientID + "','" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + lb1.ClientID + "')";
                txt2.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript:return UpdateField('" + chk.ClientID + "','" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + lb1.ClientID + "')";


            }
        }
```

It is not working.. I cant understand why?? Isn't it the correct way to add attributes to the check boxes,text boxes??? Or Should I have to change the post back of Label of Sum??

Comment: Watch the `ChkId` parameter of the `UpdateField` function. You are using it as `chkID`. It should be exactly the same, case sensitive wise.

Comment: LOL...Thats Correct!!!!!!!!TX mate!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch the ChkId parameter of the UpdateField function. You are using it as chkID. It should be exactly the same, case sensitive wise.